# How to delete / remove a connection present between two shapes in Kendo Diagram.?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, diagram

```js
var diagram = $("#diagram").getKendoDiagram();
var connId = diagram.connections[i].id;
```

How can I delete a connection present in between two shapes in Kendo Diagram.
I can get id of that connection and from/to it is connected.

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/diagram/methods/remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete a connection in the diagram by passing its object to the diagram.remove function.
Like.

```js
var diagram = $("#diagram").getKendoDiagram();
var conn = diagram.connections[0];
diagram.remove(conn);
```

Example is at https://dojo.telerik.com/IBAlIXov